# Resize option for Selected Dates across multiple months in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I just started using Full Calendar 4. Its awesome.
All things working great.

I am including a functionality to resize already selected dates across multiple months. For example, I select dates in April, and I want to continue my selection to 10th of May, But I think currently it is not possible.

I am trying to make it work like:

Click on next month, save current selected dates, by holding Ctrl or Shift keys, click on other dates and adding those dates to previous selected dates.

I went through new feature requests and issues, but this exact feature did not listed there.
Just curious to ask that if any other possible work around to this functionality or am I doing it right?

Comment: there's no right or wrong way to do it. You're correct that it's not something which is directly provided by the fullCalendar package. So you can implement such a thing however you wish in order to provide the right experience for your users. For example another option would be to pop up a modal box where the user gets to enter the new start and end dates in a text field. I'm not saying that's a better solution, I'm just making the point that you have a free choice to design it however you like.

Comment: You can also consider [recuring events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/recurring-events) by providing event information in a kind of popup modal.